# Calculate number of seconds between two datenum in Matlab

Tags: matlab

If I do the following:

```
t1 = now;
pause(2);
t2 = now;
```

How do I calculate the difference between t2 and t1 in seconds?

```
dt = t2 - t1
```

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation on `datenum` and its cousins `datevec` and `datestr`? I assume you did, otherwise you wouldn't ask here, so please, do [edit] the question containing what you learned there and why it didn't help you.

Comment: hint: how many seconds in a day ?

Comment: Don't see the problem of asking a simple question

Comment: [Handle and Convert Dates](https://mathworks.com/help/finance/handling-and-converting-dates.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using 'now', your statement

```
dt = t2 - t1
```

returns the difference in number of days. To get it to seconds, simply multiply by 24*3600:

```
dt_s = 24 * 3600 * (t2 - t1)
```

However, if you just want to measure elapsed time I would recommend using tic/toc instead

```
tic
pause(2);
dt = toc;
```

Answer (score 2):

Jakob L is right with simply multiplying by 24 * 3600.

In case you work a lot with dates and times consider using the `datetime()` function instead.

Your code would look like this:

```
t1 = datetime()
pause(2)
t2 = datetime()
dt = t2 - t1         % will give you this duration 00:00:02
```

dt is now of type `duration`. You can use the function `seconds()` to get the number of seconds

```
sec = seconds(dt) % will give you something like 2.01 seconds (round it in case you want integer seconds)
```